# Grouping Based on a Column

Tags: r

I am not sure how to tackle this. I tried brainstorming idea using dplyr, transposing, etc , but cannot think of a solution. I thought I'd ask the community for help.

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                Time = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                Y = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
```

I have listed a sample dataset above. So, trying if there is a possibility in grouping by both Time. For instance, it would be from this:

```
ID    Time     X      Y 
1     0        1      7
1     1        2      8
2     0        3      9
2     1        4     10
3     0        5     11
3     1        6     12
```

to

```
ID    Time_0.X    Time_0.Y   Time_1.X    Time_1.Y     
1            1         7            2          8
2            3         9            4         10                
3            5        11            6         12
```

Please let me know if anything comes in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple pivot wider

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                 Time = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                 X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                 Y = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))


DF %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Time,values_from = X:Y)
```

Comment: thank you so much - will try learning tidyverse in the future!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Most definitely- thank you!!